# WiFi connection on my iPad automatically gets disconnected when the screen goes off

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi

When screen goes off on my iPad, the WiFi gets disconnected automatically. How do I keep WiFi enabled?
I just noticed this problem is only when the hotspot is made by a xiaomi mobile(which makes a connected chain symbol rather than normal wifi symbol) which is the same type as the hotspot by Apple devices. This problem is not when hotspot is created by other android devices.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a common problem.
Try these simple steps provided in the first answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250285673).

Let me know if they work. If not, please, provide me more details about your iPad settings or/and iOS version.

Comment: I tried all these steps but the problem still persists. I’m using ipad 8th gen.  Software version 14.4.2

Comment: I just noticed this problem is only when the hotspot is made by a xiaomi mobile(which makes a connected chain symbol rather than normal wifi symbol) which is the same type as the hotspot by Apple devices. This problem is not when hotspot is created by other android devices.

Answer (score 0):

### Auto-Lock

I had the same problem in the first few months after I bought my iPad (in 2019). But this was also happening for iPhone hotspots (all hotspots actually). I don't know why this is happening but I noticed that when I manually lock the iPad and re-open it right after, it won't disconnect; but when I let it lock automatically, and then turn it on again, it was disconnected.

So I came to believe that Auto-Lock was to blame. Disabling it solved the problem.

To disable Auto-Lock, go to **Settings > Display & Brightness > Auto-Lock** and set it to "**Never**".

The major inconvenient of this solution is that you will need to lock your phone manually each time.